# How to add <span> tag during runtime in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In my website I am having 2 tables - album and images.

> album contains aid, alname. similarly image contains - imgid, imgname,
>   imgurl, imgdes and aid [Foreign Key].

This is my gallery.aspx page:

```
<body style="background-image:url('Images/Backgrounds/back.jpg')">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1 style="color:White"><i>Gallery - Albums</i></h1>
        <div id="container" runat="server" style="border-style:ridge; border-color:dimgrey; height:565px; padding-left:50px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this is my code-behind:

```
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();
com = new SqlCommand("select * from album", con);
reader = com.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
dtnew.Load(reader);
DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[6];
con.Close();
if (dtnew.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtnew.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        con.Open();

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dtnew.Rows[i]["aid"]);
        DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from image where aid=" + id + " ORDER BY aid desc", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = com1.ExecuteReader();
        dttemp.Load(dr);
        dt[i] = dttemp;
        ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(dt[i].Rows[0]["imgurl"]);
        img.ID = Convert.ToString(dtnew.Rows[i]["aid"]);
        img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Img1_Click);
        img.AlternateText = Convert.ToString(dtnew.Rows[i]["alname"]);
        img.ToolTip = Convert.ToString(dtnew.Rows[i]["alname"]);
        img.CssClass = "galimg";

        con.Close();

        container.Controls.Add(img);
    }
}
```

This code only loads 1st image in the Image Button and shows it as Album and when clicked it will be loading another page where all the images relating to that album.

This is how it looks now:

[image]

What I want now is I jus want a span or section of div to be added alongwith each imagebutton in the loop. so that this imagebutton will have some background with width and height greater than the Image button.. How can I achieve this.

How can I do this in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your imagebutton to an `HtmlGenericControl` - so just before each button you can create a new html control, then add your button to it and add it to your page.

The constructor of the `HtmlGenericControl` class takes the tag name of your HTML control, so it's easy to change it from a `span` to a `div` - just pass `"div"` in instead.

You can use this `HtmlGenericControl` class to create any html elements you like.

So...something like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl s = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
s.Attributes.Add("class", "myCssClass");
s.Attributes.Add("id", "myUniqueIdButNotNeeded");
// then your button as normal
ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
// rest of your button code...

// add button to span
s.Controls.Add(img);

// add the span
container.Controls.Add(s);
```

Comment: Give me a second.. I'l Try... :)

Comment: Wow bro... Works Perfect... As expected... Thanks alot... :) +1

Comment: @Darren...  Now I have one more problem. Do you see that border surrounding the images in the pic i have uploaded. Those will remain constant because of height of span tag I set using HtmlGenericControl. When there are more number of Images, the bottomline of the span surrounding it will remain same height and the images flow out of the container div.. What can do for this.. Help me out if you know??

Comment: @Darren.. got the solution for that.. We need to use overflow in the span.. Thank you for replying... Hey do u have knowledge about <expires> and caching.. If yes pls let me knw... :)

Comment: I do, though it's a little open ended to answer here. You're better off asking a fresh question or search this site for the answer, caching has been addressed many times :)

Comment: @Darren.. I have asked the question and searched for the same in here.. But din got any ultimate solution for my ques.. Can we chat in gmail or some other if you don't mind.. :)

Comment: I dont have time to chat, sorry. Got a link to your Q?

Comment: @Darren.. This is the link to my ques!!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345146/how-to-make-webpage-load-faster-using-expires-or-caching-method

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `HtmlControl` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.aspx

```
HtmlControl mySpan = new HtmlControl("span")
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time to answer my ques.. +1..:)